# Get NetInfo using async function

Tags: react-native

I have a function named `hasNetwork` and i want return network connectivity status.

I try using following code and call function when component gets focus :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {

        let hasNetwork = this.hasNetwork();
        console.log(hasNetwork); // Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
    });
}
// ===========================================

// Functions
async hasNetwork() {
    await NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
        if (isConnected) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I expect function returns true or false but it returns Promise !. any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `hasNetwork` is also `async`, you need to `await` on that function as well.
To make an anonymous function `async`, just add `async` before the parameters.

Also, since `Network.isConnected.fetch()` returns a promise that returns a true/false value anyway, you could just use that directly without needing to use `then`.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', async () => {

        let hasNetwork = await Network.isConnected.fetch();
        console.log(hasNetwork);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.i found that if i return value(true or false) out of ```NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then()``` it works. your answer is more efficient.